# confused about prototype chain behaviour in js

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(name,city) {
this.name = name;
this.address.city = city;
}
Person.prototype.address = { city: "x"};
var p1 = new Person("Tony","A");
var p2 = new Person("Sam", "B");
console.log([p1==p2, p1.address == p2.address, p1.address.city == p2.address.city])
console.log( p1.address)
console.log( p2.address)

> Array [false, true, true]
> Object { city: "B" }
> Object { city: "B" }
```

As the result demonstrates, p1 and p2 obviously share the same address property from the prototype chain. But why it happens this way, is it like that all properties of type object on an object will not get its own location to store data during initialization and will only use reference on prototype?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes". ;)

Comment: why p1 and p2 does not have its own reference to create an object with city property in it during initialization?

Comment: Because you created that property on the prototype (only one object). If you want each object to have their own address, then define it in the constructor and not on the prototype.

Comment: yeah, i got it, thx